# Find out why Jenkins CI job is triggered by another CI job

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have two CI jobs (A and B) that build two different Maven reactors (A and B) that contain several modules. Anyhow, Jenkins detects that after building job A it must trigger job B. And after building of job B it triggers job A again (circular triggering).

I examined all reactor modules and its dependencies. From my point of view, I eliminated all (transitive) dependencies from reactor A to reactor B. But Jenkins still executes this circle.

How can I find out, why exactly Jenkins decides to trigger job B? There must be a detailed explanation on Jenkins-side?

I found this plugin but unfortunately it's not compatible with my Jenkins version: https://plugins.jenkins.io/depgraph-view/

**Jenkins version:** 1.651.3

Comment: Jenkins version 1.651.3 ? Really that old? From 2016 Wow (I strongly recommend to go to a most recent version..)  ... Are there dependencies defined between the jobs .. ?

Comment: There are no explicit dependencies like "building another project when done" etc. Both jobs start building when there are SCM changes on dependent projects. One important thing comes to my mind: Both reactors are part of the same repository and both Jenkins jobs fetch this repo. I tried sparse checkout and "excluded the directory path region" of the other reactor (and vise-versa). But it didn't help.

Comment: One repository and several multi module projects in it? That the issue... You should separate them and create separate jobs/repositories(depending on the version control tool you are using)...